# XPath for pagination non link site

Tags: xpath

how to extract pagination this link (non link site ) by xpath

code:

```
<a class="pager_item" href="javascript:" data-page="2">2</a>
```

and i want get pagination link is:

```
https://www.sitename.com/search/phone/?pageno=2
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Are you trying to extract `2` from the `<a>` tag and insert it at the end of that url?

Comment: i want get pagination link is:
https://www.sitename.com/search/phone/?pageno=2

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
//a/@data-page
```

should resolve to `2`.

Then, depending on language/library you are using, you declare the base url (`https://www.sitename.com/search/phone/?pageno=`) as one variable, the output of that xpath expression as another variable, and then concatenate the two into the final url.

Comment: how add site link + //a/@data-page?

Comment: @franky50 - Can you use Python?